# Would a repair of the 64-bit installation MBR using 32-bit LiveCD be compatible?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, mbr, 32-bit, livecd

My aging computer runs an i5-760 on a P7P55D-E Pro.
The primary OS on this was Win 7 on a SATA drive.

A used HP 80GB IDE drive came my way upon which I've installed 64-bit Ubuntu with a GRUB loader.

I *suspect* the MBR may be corrupt. Booting into Windows fails and recurrently brings me to the System Repair menu. Booting into Ubuntu fails with a "kernel panic". The boot-repair tool created [this summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23780629/)

My interpretation, as a nouveau, is that the 'boot' flag has gone walkabout from /dev/sdb. The blocker in running the repair tool is that the LiveCD I run is a 32-bit Trusty whereas the corrupt installation is a 64-bit Xenial.

Could there be compatibility issues repairing a 64-bit installation MBR using 32-bit LiveCD boot-repair tool?

Answer (score 0):

No, the MBR bootcode will most likely be identical (mixed 16/32 bit) regardless of what kernel it ultimately decides to boot.

Comment: I was also looking around on the cloud for references to help me answer this question ... [ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917) writes to say 'If the GRUB you want to repair is located in a 64bits distribution, you need to install & use Boot-Repair from a 64 bit distribution.'